# Moviepy write_videofile changes number of video and audio frames even after using 'rawvideo' as the codec parameter

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am using moviepy (Python) to read video and audio frames of a video and after making some changes I am writing them back to a videofile, say new.avi, to preserve the changes, or to avoid compression, I am using codec= 'rawvideo' in write_videofile function. But when I read the video and audio frames back, the number of video and audio frames are different than when they were when written, they are usually increased.
Can anybody tell me the reason,? is it because of the ffmpeg used or some other reason? Does it happen always or there is some problem in my machine? Thank you :-)